# Asignar objeto JSON a value en Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

he realizado un par de test en Angular 2, y me gustaría resolver una duda.

Ahora mismo trabajo con un simple select, e intento recibir un objeto JSON realizando una selección en él.

**FUNCIONA**
Funciona si quiero recibir tan sólo una parte del JSON (adjunto un ejemplo):

**JSON**

```
export class Coche{
  nombre: String;
  dueños: [{
    nombre: String;
  }];
  vendedores: [{
    nombre: String;
  }];
}
```

Si realizo lo siguiente, funciona:
**HTML**

```
<select #coche (change)="getCoches(coche.value);" >
    <option type="text" *ngFor="let coche of coches" value="{{coche.nombre}}" >{{coche.nombre}}</option>                        
</select>
```

**TS**

```
   getCoches(nombre: string): void {
        console.log(scenario);
}
```

**NO FUNCIONA**
Pero si realizo lo siguiente, no:

**HTML**

```
<select  #coche (change)="getCoches(coche.value);" >
    <option type="text" *ngFor="let coche of coches" value="{{coche}}" >{{coche.nombre}}</option>                       
</select>
```

**TS**

```
 getCocches(coche: Coche): void {
        console.log(coche);
}
```

La diferencia es que envío un objeto completo (coche) y no un elemento de éste (coche.nombre). ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Espero que ese getCo**c**ches sea una errata en la pregunta y no en el código

Comment: Lo es. Ahora corrijo el ejemplo. La pregunta es como mandar un objeto JSON completo a  través de value.

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo quieres mandar el objeto coche como valor, ¿cierto?, pondré de ejemplo como yo lo haría:

Componente.html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="cocheSelected" name="select-coche" required>
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Selecciona un coche</option>
<option *ngFor="let coche of coches" [ngValue]="coche">{{coche.Modelo}}</option>
</select>
```

Componente.ts

```
export class Coche {
   coches: Coche[] = [{Id: 1, Modelo: "Scania S"}, {Id: 2, Modelo: "Volvo XL"}];
   cocheSelected: Coche;
   constructor() {}
}
```

---

Esa seria la forma de usar Select con Object , la forma primitiva sería:

Componente.ts

```
cocheSelected = null;
public coches= [
    {Id: 1, Modelo: "Scania S"}, {Id: 2, Modelo: "Volvo XL"}
];
```

Componente.html

```
<select name="select-coche" [(ngModel)]="cocheSelected">
        <option *ngFor="let coche of coches" [value]="coche.Id">  
        {{coche.Modelo}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

Espero ser entendible :-D